# ArcPy: check in and out of Advanced/Standard concurrent license

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-license-manager

Is it possible to check in and out of a concurrent license straight from ArcPy. For example, sometimes I need to use a `buffer right` or `find duplicates`. Both tools require ArcPy advanced or Standard. Although we have a large amount of Basic licenses, we have a small amount of concurrent standard/advanced licenses.

Is it possible to do the following (Pseudo code):

```
# ...

# Pseudo code:
if license == 'BASIC':
   check_in('STANDARD')
   func_that_does_buff_right(data)
   check_out('STANDARD')
   check_in('BASIC')
```

Comment: I know you can check out extensions but I don't think this is possible with standard arcpy. Have you looked at [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000000z000000)

Comment: As per @ChrisR 's link it seems you can import the licences (e.g.: import arcview) as long as that is *before* importing arcpy. If you try importing a different licence level will that replace the previous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried this:

```
import arcview
import arcpy

print(arcpy.ProductInfo())

import arcinfo

print(arcpy.ProductInfo())
```

This was the output:

```
ArcView
ArcView
```

Not sure if this is the correct approach but looks arcpy didn't change it after trying to import a higher level no error though.

**Edit:** As per the comments it seems this task cannot be completed within the same session as shown in the OP's pseudo code. That is to say once a license level has been imported it will persist throughout the session regardless of whether a new/higher level license import statement has been executed. There may be a workaround such as creating a separate script to handle higher level geoprocessing ect.

Comment: Ya, the idea is that to only import ArcInfo for the specific task that it's required for and then checks it out after. some of these scripts could take hours to perform and I don't want to hog the license manager for a 5 minute operation. The alternative would be to move the arcinfo required code into its own script and only be used when required then. Furthermore, when I import ArcInfo, Desktop license manager doesn't seem to change my license. Potential bug?

Comment: Ya I was thinking the same thing using separate scripts may be a hassle though. As far as the bug not sure sometimes I have had to close the script then reopen it to change the level, for example if I run the above script then change the first import to arcinfo and save it and run wont change unless I exit the script then rerun it.